# wilson score interval possible results range

Tags: algorithm, popularity

This question is about Wilson score confidence interval (see [here](https://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html) for explanation).

I do not completly understand the scoring equation:
[image: equaltion]
<sub>(source: [evanmiller.org](http://www.evanmiller.org/rating-equation.png))</sub>

But..
I just need to know what is the range of the possible results.

I need to give 1 out of 3 medals to the user accordig to the rate.

(I have recipes created by users, can do "Like" on them, and accordingly I calculate the rate of the recipe. User rate is calculated according to his recipes rates.)

Thanks
Yoav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation is returning bounds on a probability, so the range should be greater than or equal to zero and less than or equal to 1.